# Data type of command line args

Tags: c, attributes, typing

I'm struggling to convert an executable program into a function that I can call from within my main routine. As it currently is written, the executable looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    //do stuff
    if(setxattr(argv[4], tmpstr, argv[3], strlen(argv[3]), 0)){
        perror("setxattr error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //do more stuff
}
```

I can call this as follows and it works successfully:

> ./set_attributes -s encrypted 1 ~/text.txt

But now I want to move this into a function embedded in another program. The part that is failing is `strlen(argv[3])`.  My new function looks like this:

```
int set_encr_attr(char* fpath, int value) {
    
    char* userstr = NULL;
    
    /* Check that the value to set is either 0 or 1 */
    if (!( (value == 0) || (value == 1) )) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    //do stuff (including malloc(userstr)
    strcpy(userstr, XATTR_USER_PREFIX);

    /* Set attribute */
    if(setxattr(fpath, userstr, value, 1, 0)){
        perror("setxattr error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see, I've replaced that fourth argument with the number 1, since I've already checked that the value being passed in is either 0 or 1, thus it must have a strlen of 1. I've tried a few other things, but I always get this error:

> xattr_new.c: In function ‘set_encr_attr’:
>
> xattr_new.c:52:2: warning:
> passing argument 3 of ‘setxattr’ makes pointer from integer without a
> cast [enabled by default]
>
> /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/xattr.h:40:12: note: expected ‘const
> void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’

When I play with this, I can see that strlen(argv[3]) == 1, so I don't understand why I can't just replace this with the integer 1. As for the typing issue, I've tried casting (which I think is generally a bad idea), but I can't make it work.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`1` is an integer, `"1"` is a string, a character array of length 2, containing the ASCII character '1' (value 49) followed by a null byte (terminator). The function doesn't want an integer, it wants a char pointer. `strlen("1")` = 1 because the string is delimited by the null byte.

Comment: Thanks. I understand all of that, but I still don't see the solution. Among the many things that I have substituted for that argument are "1", strlen("1"), as well as declaring a char* and assigning it a value of 1 (and a null terminator).

Comment: In the new code you posted, the third argument to setxattr is an int. It needs to be a char pointer, like in your original code. You are trying to pass an INTEGER, not a string!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using atoi() to convert your arguments to integers before passing them to your function? Not clear to me why you would want to pass a number as a character string, if you didn't have to.